# MPMoviePlayerController doesn't play newly saved video file

Tags: iphone, ios, video, uiimagepickercontroller, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm using an imagePickerController to record video. In the `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` function I'm trying to set the video to a previously defined MPMoviePlayerController:

```
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]){
    NSURL *movieUrl = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    [self.moviePlayer setContentURL:movieUrl]];
}
```

This is working fine and the video is indeed playing.
But I want to save the file for later use. When I do this and use the saved file for the moviePlayer, nothing happens:

- I've tried this (saving the data to a new file)

  ```
  NSString *directory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *newPath = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myMovie.mov"];
  NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:movieUrl];
  [videoData writeToFile:newPath atomically:NO];
  [self.moviePlayer setContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newPath]];
  ```
- or this (copying the temp video file to my document folder)

  ```
  NSString *directory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *newPath = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myMovie.mov"];
  NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
  NSError *error = nil;
  [fileManager copyItemAtPath:[videoUrl path] toPath:newPath error:&error];
  [self.moviePlayer setContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newPath]];
  ```

Without any success, even though the file at `newPath` does exist... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Has the file completed writing before you attempt to play the video back?  Try setting a timer delay on playback of a second or so to see if that allows the video to play?

Comment: well, I've tried to add: NSLog(@"exists: %@", [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:newPath]?@"yes":@"no"); and the log is "yes". Also If I wait and try to set the file at newPath to self.moviePlayer nothing happens either

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok I finally found the issue. The problem was not in fact with the MPMoviePlayerController but with the line:

```
[self.moviePlayer setContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newPath]];
```

I fixed it by replacing that line with:

```
[self.moviePlayer setContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:newPath isDirectory:NO]];
```

Hope that will help someone else!

Comment: Thx :D but WTH!! isDirectory :S UGH :S

Comment: @Johann if I were God, you would go strait to heaven for this post. THANK YOU.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work. I download mp3 file about 20%, then play it while continue to download 80% left. but the player can play until 20% then stop.

Answer (score 1):

use the code below:

```
NSData *movieData;  
    NSError *dataReadingError = nil;        
    movieData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: movieURL options:NSDataReadingMapped error:&dataReadingError];        
    if(movieData != nil)        
        NSLog(@"Successfully loaded the data.");   
    else        
        NSLog(@"Failed to load the data with error = %@", dataReadingError);
```