# Where to store video in iOS like UIImage?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am saving image in UIImage like:

```
  newImage=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl options:0 error:&err]];
```

After this i want to fetch the video from the web and store it for further use which type of variable should i use for storing the video?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to download video from server. Then save the downloaded data to Document directory. You can play video either using AVPlayer, or MPMoviePlayer. Refer this post [playing local video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012444/mpmovieplayercontroller-doesnt-play-newly-saved-video-file)